# Keyboard on my HP Compaq is messing up keys.

Tags: 16.04

For e.g.

Pressing "z" or "1" gives "z1", "m" or "7" gives "m7",

The lower row of alphabets, and top num eric row is giving same kind of characters.

Keyboard doesn't have Numlock Key.

My last row and number row gives:
"z1x2c3v4bnm7,8.9/0" instead of "zxcvbnm,./"

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Ubuntu based distros I have tried have a keyboard choice(ex chinese,American,etc)on the installer.American is usually the default,so if you set your system back to default settings,you should get American type keyboard setup.There is a post on how to do that.I just used it the oyher day to fix something I messed up accidentally.